# What is a word to indicate a single item when multiple items are available elsewhere?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I have a website where I am directing users to take successive evaluations. In the default case, users see three options:

- initial
- follow-up
- reassessment

However, not all entries have all three options. There are certain conditions where an entry can only take the initial evaluation. To avoid confusion, I've removed the "follow-up" and "reassessment" options in cases where the user can't take them. That leaves an "initial" option there by itself.

I don't feel that "initial" is the right word when it's the only available choice. I'd prefer to not remove the label, since the page is meant to show multiple entries in a dashboard arrangement.

What single, descriptive word could I use in this instance?

Comment: Just call it “Evaluation”

Comment: This might be a better question for ux.stackexchange.com. For instance, you might list all 3 entries, but disable the ones that aren't available for that instance. This avoids the terminology problem.

Comment: If it's the default then call it the *default*.

Comment: There is no word nor phrase to indicate a single item when multiple items are available elsewhere.
If it matters to you then please remember, marketing questions need to be clear to the whole target audience. Since no-one has any opportunity to ask for clarification, that means you must pitch everything at the lowest common denominator… not the perfect or any kind of average target.
That means if, say, your target is 16-26, you need to make sense to most 16-year-olds.
That in mind, re-phrase the whole question so you're sure every part of it makes sense to 16-year-olds.
Does that not help?

Comment: An *assessment* may or may not have a followup.

Comment: @jxh This is such a simple and elegant way to phrase this.

Answer (score 1):

After the helpful series of comments on this question, I realized I was overthinking the problem. I decided to remove the heading and simply use "evaluation" when there is only one option, and label them differently in other conditions. Here is the final result below with all three conditions.

[image]